# JQuery method not firing from code behind when using a RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with a jQuery method being called from code behind when using a RequiredFieldValidator. This works great without the RequiredFieldValidator on the form. When it's on the form, I get an error:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'toastmessage'**

as if it hasn't loaded the jquery.js file.

As a test, I have a simple page that has a TextBox on it and a button within an UpdatePanel. When you click the button, it fires the server side OnClick method with the following code:

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alert", @"$().toastmessage('showWarningToast', 'Record Saved Successfully.'); ", true);
```

This works great, and pops the message. When I attach a RequiredFieldValidator to the TextBox is when the error pops up. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you post the markup of the text box and required field validator?

Comment: Can we get an update on your question by either posting the markup or indicating if it was solved?

Comment: Lawrence's answer took care of the problem. I actually read into that property incorrectly and at one point tried it, but used "true" which obviously didn't work. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Required Field Validator:

```
EnableClientScript="false"
```